# How to filter words in Java?

Tags: java

I want to check if there are 'bad' words in some cases such as checking IDs in register form. But I do not know how to check it.. The bottom code is what I got far with it.

```
String words = "admin,administrator,babo,sir,melon";

public boolean checkWord(String input) {
   if(something here that i need to find??) return false;
   else return true;
}
```

The pattern of words are divided in comma, and I really need help with it please!

Comment: For each word, check if the input contains/equals?

Comment: I think I did not get the question properly. You want to look for individual words or you want to check if your String input contains any of those words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example if you want to look for group of words inside your input

```
public class TestCheckWord {
    static String words = "admin,administrator,babo,sir,melon";
    public static void main (String args[]){        
        System.out.println(checkWord("Hello melon"));
        System.out.println(checkWord("Hello sir"));
        System.out.println(checkWord("Hello you"));
    }
    public static boolean checkWord(String input) {
        String wordArray[] = words.split(",");
        for(int i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++){
            if(input.indexOf(wordArray[i])>-1)
                return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and yet even another way to look for words only if your input contains only one word.(the order in the array doesn't matter in this case.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class TestCheckWord2 {
    public static void main (String args[]){        
        System.out.println(checkWord("babo"));
        System.out.println(checkWord("bobo"));      
    }
    private static String[] WORDS =  {"admin", "babo", "melon", "sir", "administrator"};
    private static Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(WORDS));
    public static boolean checkWord(String input) { 
        return mySet.contains(input);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use a binary search instead of a linear search. (you'll have to sort the array first)

Comment: do not forget to lowercase the input. Otherwise if it have capital letters it will not work ;)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing would be to search for a word in a sorted array, like this:

```
private static String[] WORDS = new String[] {
    "admin", "administrator", "babo", "melon", "sir"
};

public boolean checkWord(String input) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(WORDS, input) < 0; // Not found
}
```

Comment: As a note, this method will work **only** if the array is sorted. OP's example shows a sorted `String` array.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP's example has `"sir"` and `"melon"` reversed, I needed to sort them manually to make it work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But I did - the introductory sentence says that the array must be sorted.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or not getting it, Is this only to verify if the input is just in the array (just a word) or if the input "contains" any of the words of the array??

Comment: @PbxMan This returns `true` if the word `input` is *not* present in the array of `WORDS` (supposedly, these are prohibited words).

Comment: I know how it works, but I think I got the question the wrong way, because if you want to find if one word is in your list of forbidden words there many other better ways to tackle this such us reg. expressions, putting them in a map, etc.

Comment: @PbxMan Ah, of course there's a dozen of other equally good ways to do it - a hash set, a tree set, a list with a linear search, a regexp, a string with delimiters, and so on. I picked this one because its initialization is simple, and because it makes the check a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class steve {

    
    static boolean checkWord(String input, String words) {
        if(words.contains(input)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String words = "admin,administrator,babo,sir,melon";
        
        System.out.print(steve.checkWord("babo",words));
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code, and how it solves the problem for the OP

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.